# Change site configuration without restarting G-WAN

Tags: webserver, g-wan

I'm looking at hosting a number of small, static websites and have been looking at a few alternatives including G-WAN.  At the moment I'm just trying to get a feel for how well each server suits my needs before picking one.

G-WAN seems to do exactly what I want, though I'm running into problems with updating the configuration (by adding new folders) after the server's started.  I can't find anything in the documentation or online about this, so I don't know if I'm doing anything dumb, running an unsupported configuration, or whether it's a feature that doesn't exist in G-WAN.

**Here's my setup:**

G-WAN 3.3.28 64-bit on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

I have what I think is the required minimal folder structure:

```
0.0.0.0_80
  #0.0.0.0
    www
  $site.com
    www
  $othersite.com
    www
```

I startup gwan via (I'm still messing around, so hopefully ):

```
sudo .\gwan -d
```

Everything works brilliantly.  I add $thirdsite.com/, $thirdsite.com/www/, and $thirdsite.com/www/index.html; then when I try to visit thirdsite.com it gives me the root host (ie it doesn't seem to pick up the changes).

To reload the modified configuration, I have to either do:

```
sudo .\gwan -k; sudo .\gwan -d
```

or kill the non-angel process (kill -s 15) to restart the child process.

Can G-WAN reload the host definitions another way?  If so, is it something that works out of the box or is there a command that can cycle the server without dropping requests made to other hosts (/is it safe to kill -s 15 on the non-angel process + if so, is there a reliable way to identify the process)?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G-WAN loads the host definitions at startup and does not check them as time goes to reload them dynamically.

To force a reload, you have to stop the child process (when in daemon mode) and v3.9+ keeps the old child alive the time to process any pending request while the new child accepts new connections.

Since stopping the child can also be done from the `maintenance` script or from a `handler` or from a `servlet` by just running `exit(0)` there is not need for a dedicated command.

Note that when you use `kill` you can pick the `pid` file from the `gwan` directory:

- the `parent` process starts with a capital letter: `G`wan_xxxx.pid
- the `child` process starts with a lowercase letter: `g`wan_xxxx.pid

That will make your life easier.

Comment: Awesome, that answers my question - being able to kill the process from somewhere else reliably was all I really need.  Thanks!